# How do I install the Overdrive lending library program on Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr
Wine 1.6.2
Windows Installer (msiexec) 4.5.6001.22299

Overdrive Media Console is a Windows application running on Windows XP SP3 or later.  Overdrive is used by lending libraries to lend ebook, audio, and video files, but only to registered members of a library.  There is no Ubuntu package.

I downloaded the ODMediaConsoleSetup.msi file from http://app.overdrive.com/, saved it, and made it executable.  Then I ran Wine thus:

```
$ wine msiexec /i ODMediaConsoleSetup.msi
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions" returned 1603
```

After googling I could not find any references to my problem.  Has anybody been here before and succeeded in installing Overdrive?

Regards,
Hedley

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem until I used winecfg to change the Windows version from XP to Win 7. The installer ran and I was then able to download an MP3 audiobook.

Comment: Sadly I cannot give either of you the point since my install of POL keeps crashing. If I get that fixed I'll be sure to reward one of you.

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the "Windows Desktop" version into **PlayonLinux** and got good results.

You'll have too choose [Install] and then [Install non-listed Program].
Then you'll choose [Install a program in a new virtual drive] then name it "Overdrive" or whatever you want.  Check the boxes for [Use another version of Wine]  and [Install some libraries]. You'll need to install wine 1.4 if you don't have it.

To install wine 1.4 go to the main Playonlinux window and choose [tools] from the top menu and then [Manage Wine Versions]

After choosing wine 1.4 you'll pick "32 bit windows installation" and next. In the next window you'll see a list of add-ons that start with "POL_" you want to scroll down almost to the bottom and look for "POL_Install_wmp10" this will install windows media player 10 which is the backend of the OMC. Now you'll need to download the "Windows Desktop" version of OverDrive Media Console if you haven't already from http://app.overdrive.com/images/windows-phone-store.png
choose [select another file] [next] and then [Browse] and once you've picked your downloaded file (ODMediaConsoleSetup.msi] and opened it you're done.

Also if you don't like playonlinux you can used [this method](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27541). It used winetricks.

Comment: These instructions worked perfectly.  The only problem was I needed to run wmplayer 10 once and accept the license agreement before overdrive could connect and download a DRM protected audiobook from a local library.